# upgrade mendeley to experimental release through command line

Tags: command-line, upgrade, 16.10, beta, mendeley

I installed `mendeleydesktop` through terminal on Ubuntu 16.10. Current installed version is 1.17.8. I have chosen to "Opt-in to Experimental Releases" from the Help->Check for updates option inside the GUI. These days I am getting notification of upgrading to new version (1.17.9-dev2). I want to do the upgrade. Please check the attached image. I tried to upgrade through the terminal by the command `sudo apt-get upgrade mendeleydesktop`. I even tried `sudo apt-get upgrade mendeleydesktop -d` but I am getting the following message every time.

"mendeleydesktop is already the newest version (1.17.8)."

[mendeley notification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DihYq.png)

Answer (score 1):

The program probably checks with the website if there is a newer version, and finds that there is. However, this newer version is not yet in the Ubuntu repository. Your two options are:

1. to ignore the message for now, and do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade mendeleydesktop` from time to time to see if the new version is in the repository yet; or
2. to download and install the new version from the web site. Look out for any instructions about installing the new version *over* an older one.